# error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I have to install wordcloud in jupyter but during process 
'pip install wordcloud' 
i stuck on error
'error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. 
I have read related solution on stackoverflow but there is no any satisfied answer :(

Comment: Have you tried installing Microsoft Visual C++ 14 like the error suggests?

Comment: no visual studio are more than 1 gb so i want to ignore

Comment: If you want to use pip install from that source, you will have to do what it says. However, I have had cases where I need to build something on a small VM, so I just build it on another system and copy in the binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing a precompiled version from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud), select the wheel file for your python version, download it and then do

```
pip install <name of wheel file>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Binary install**

use the binary-only option for pip. For example, for wordcloud:

```
pip install --only-binary :all: wordcloud
```