# Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 installed but not found

Tags: c++, python-3.x, visual-studio, box2d

I (Windows 10) am trying to building `pybox2d` from source using [these instructions](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/blob/master/INSTALL.md#building-from-source-windows)

What I did:

1. Install MinGW and MsyS [from here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/). (Installed `mingw-developer-toolkit`, `mingw32-base`, `mingw32-gcc-g++`, `msys-base`)
2. Download SWIG [from here](http://www.swig.org/download.html), unpacked it, and added it to my environmental variables.
3. cloned the [repo](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/)
4. When I run `python setup.py build` I get an error

> `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools`

I have however installed [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) and [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 RC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685)

And looking at `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` I see that it is installed. (?)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

---

These SO posts are similar, but distinct 
[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50696411/distutils-errors-distutilsplatformerror-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required),
[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513255/error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Comment: The _redistributables_ have nothing to do with installing visual studio - installing them doesn't install visual studio. They exist to let people _run_ apps built with visual studio.

Comment: What should I install then?

Comment: Do what the error tells you to do?  "Get it with  < LINK > "

Comment: The link http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools doesn't work

Comment: Actually you need either mingw or vc++, not both.

Comment: Try here instead: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: Someone should complain to the developers that the URL has changed (if there is not a bug report already).

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671800/7976758 that seems to help - some components should be added during installation - not only default ones